# AS3 error 1084 syntax error expecting rightparen before dot

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, runtime-error, flash-cs3

i am new to this whole as3 thing and i am struggling immensely. I have been sat for the last two days trying to do something i can imaging to be simple to everyone else reading this. I am trying to create a game where i have a skate boarder controlled by the keyboard keys. However when i type this code in i am getting a 1084 error please help before i throw my laptop out the window. Thanks!!

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;enter code here

    public class skatefate extends MovieClip {

            var the_skater:Sprite = new Sprite();
            the_skater.addChild:(skater);



            var moveLeft:Boolean = false;
            var moveRight:Boolean = false;
            var moveUp:Boolean = false;
            var moveDown:Boolean = false;

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressedUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveskater);

            function keyPressedDown(event:KeyboardEvent) {
                if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                moveLeft = true;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                moveRight = true;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 65) {
                moveUp = true;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 90) {
                moveDown = true;
    }
}


            function keyPressedUp(event:KeyboardEvent) {
                if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                moveLeft = false;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                moveRight = false;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 65) {
                moveUp = false;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 90) {
                moveDown = false;
    }
}


            function moveskater(event:Event) {
            var speed:uint = 20;

            if (moveLeft) {
            skater.x -= speed;
            if (skater.x < 0){
        skater.x = 800;
        }
    }
            }
    if (moveRight) {
        skater.x += speed;
        if (skater.x > 800){
        skater.x = 0;
        }
    }
    if (moveUp) {
        skater.y -= speed;
        if (skater.y > 0){
        skater.y = 0;               
    }
    }
    if (moveDown) {
        skater.y += speed;
        if (skater.y > 0){
            skater.y = 0;


            }
    }
```

Comment: change `the_skater.addChild:(skater);` to `the_skater.addChild(skater);`

Comment: and, you should write in construcor.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code but didn't get your error. Your sample throws other errors & problems.
So my advice is these two things..

1. The correct to construct your code...

   ```
   package  
   {

   //IMPORTS go here

   //Declare your Class
   public class skatefate extends MovieClip 
   {
       //VARS go here 
       //*******************************************************************
       //note: later you may also add other VARS inside functions as needed 
       //(but were not originally put (declared) in this section)
       //*******************************************************************

       //Declare main function of your Class (must have same name as Class (.as)
       public function skatefate() 
       {
           //Constructor code here
           //************************************************************************
           // Your main program code and related functions (K/board etc) go here and 
           // will reference your VARS declared above in public Class construction)
           //************************************************************************

       } //End of (public) Function

   } //End of (public) Class 

   } //End of Package
   ```
2. Just incase you still struggle, this edit of your code shown should compile. From there you can study & learn. Hopefully one more laptop will survive in this cruel world.

   ```
   package 
   {
       import flash.display.*;
       import flash.events.*; //enter code here

   //Declare your Class
   public class skatefate extends MovieClip {

   var the_skater:Sprite = new Sprite();
   var skater:Sprite = new Sprite(); //hide line if skater exists already (i.e in  Library)
   var speed:uint = 20;

   //Declare main function of your Class
   public function skatefate () 
   {
       var moveLeft:Boolean = false;
       var moveRight:Boolean = false;
       var moveUp:Boolean = false;
       var moveDown:Boolean = false;

       stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);
       stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressedUp);
       stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveskater);


       the_skater.addChild(skater);
       addChild(the_skater); //adds to stage

       function keyPressedDown (event:KeyboardEvent) 
       {
           if (event.keyCode == 37)        { moveLeft = true; } 
           else if (event.keyCode == 39)   { moveRight = true; }
           else if (event.keyCode == 65)   { moveUp = true; } 
           else if (event.keyCode == 90)   { moveDown = true; }
       }

       function keyPressedUp (event:KeyboardEvent) 
       {
           if (event.keyCode == 37)        { moveLeft = false; } 
           else if (event.keyCode == 39)   { moveRight = false; }
           else if (event.keyCode == 65)   { moveUp = false; } 
           else if (event.keyCode == 90)   { moveDown = false; }
       }

       function moveskater(event:Event) 
       {
           //var speed:uint = 20; //already declared at top
           //speed = 20; // later change 'speed' this way by updating number

           if (moveLeft)   {
                               skater.x -= speed;
                               if (skater.x < 0)
                               { skater.x = 800; }
                           }

           if (moveRight)  {
                               skater.x += speed;
                               if (skater.x > 800)
                               { skater.x = 0; }
                           }

           if (moveUp)     {
                               skater.y -= speed;
                               if (skater.y > 0)
                               { skater.y = 0; }
                           }

           if (moveDown)   {   skater.y += speed;
                               if (skater.y > 0)
                               { skater.y = 0; }
                           }
       } //close 'moveskater' function


   } //End of your (public) Function

   } //End of your (public) Class 

   } //End of Package
   ```

Hope it helps. Ask for advice in the comments and don't forget to tick as "correct answer" if it works for you. That's how we say "Thanks" on Stack Overflow.